# How can solar sails be maneuvered?

Tags: photons, momentum, space-travel

Photons from the Sun are always radial to it and hence solar sails can only travel radially. Any techniques related to maneuvering?

Answer (score 1):

Well if the sails are reflective, you can tilt the sails! For a perfect reflector the transfer of momentum is then parallel to the surface vector of the sail.

You can also design multi-part sails with reflective properties controlled by liquid crystals. By making various parts of the sail more or less reflective on can change the attitude of a spinning sail - see for example the [IKAROS](http://global.jaxa.jp/press/2010/07/20100723_ikaros_e.html) experiment.

Comment: That is true if the force is due to reflected photons. Can you reflect solar wind particles? Which is more significant to impart momentum?

Comment: @Floris Solar radiation pressure is **2-3 orders of magnitude greater**.

Comment: Reflecting would still restrict its movement to within 90 degrees on all sides.

Comment: @MageshKumarGovind That is of course true. There is no magic answer. However, by speeding up or slowing down a sailship within its orbit you can let it fall or rise to a different orbit.

Answer (score 1):

You only have a problem if you start without any tangential velocity and have no reflection (or you collide with a celestial body before you have a chance to evade it).

Let us say you start in a stable orbit. Your ship has a bow and stern, in the direction of your velocity.

If you can reflect the light towards your stern, it will accelerate you and you get to a higher orbit (although you may have to change this thrust at strategic places to get the shape of your orbit right).

If you reflect it towards your bow, it slows you down and you get to a lower orbit (closer to the Sun).
If you reflect it sideways, it can change your orbital plane.

Given enough time, you can go anywhere in the Solar system.